# Can the Visual Studio IDE use long path names?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I'm using VS 2017 on Windows 10 Enterprise build 1803

I ran into trouble with a project that is deeply nested in subfolders and then I remembered reading something about Windows 10 removing the limit on MAX_PATH. I found this link [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file) which suggests that a large number of Win32 API calls can optionally not be limited to MAX_PATH.

I tried both toggling the value in the policy and changing the value in the registry. After a reboot Visual Studio still refuses to make a project in a path longer than MAX_PATH. When you browse to make the new solution it brings up a dialog [image] 
I'm looking at the list of API calls that are supposed to work with long paths and wondering just what the IDE or its tools are using that would preclude it from working? Did I not actually opt-in to long paths?

Comment: Just because the API supports it doesn't mean apps that use that API do.

Comment: If the application doesn't implement support for long path names, you can try to create a virtual drive using the [SUBST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) command.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.3.6 i still have issues with long paths. Restoring nuget packages and running tests does not succeed because of inaccessible files and folders.

As a workaround I used the [`subst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) command to associate the solutions directory temporarely to a driver letter. Thanks to IInspectable for the comment on the question about the `subst` command.