# Could not find a part of the path 'AccessibilityManagerCompat_TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor.class'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting a build error when building a Xamarin Android app:
Could not find a part of the path `AccessibilityManagerCompat_TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor.class`

Deleting the obj folder fixes it for a while. Is there a permanent fix?

Comment: I think this is an issue with your packages can you make sure you have all the latest support libraries and latest XF in case if you are using it?

Comment: I have all the latest packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.
This exception may occure by maximum path length of Solution in OS.
Check you Solution path and Move your Solution to another place e.g. root directory (C:).

Comment: Worked for me, I first tried to enable long path names but it looks like VS doesn't support them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403580/can-the-visual-studio-ide-use-long-path-names